# Cannot delete object with nil fields in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Whenever I create a new entity in core data and save the first object, the Entity always returns the saved object and a object with all fields = nil. If I try to iterate though all objects in Entity and delete, all objects with data delete except the nil object, so problem is this object with nil values for fields is always there.

Any input appreciated.

```
//get context

        var appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate;

        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!;

        var newEntry3 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TestParse", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject;

        var error : NSError? = nil;



        //Fetch request

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TestParse");

        // for beta 4 xcode only
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        var results  = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil);

        println("\n\nResults from DB \(results?.count) and teh results object \(results)\n\n");

        if results?.count > 0{




            for result : AnyObject in results! {


                println("Database object form parse: \(result.count) and contents : \(result.description)");


              // delet object and save for debugging an delete the 'nil' object                  context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject);

               context.save(&error);
                println("DELETED CORE DATA OBJECT : \(result)");
```

Comment: Show all the code and the log output

Comment: can you add the logs here?

Comment: if (results == nil) {
            // handle error // check what is the error //share the log
        } else { for result:AnyObject......}

Comment: Will add log put but essentially there are no errors and object.count =1, fetvhedResult[attribute] = nil. I wonder if this is just the object created when we create the model??

Comment: I'm getting the same result. It just keeps inserting these nil objects in Core Data. Hopefully we can get an answer soon!

Comment: Hey, it's happened to me every time I've built a core data base, I'm just ignoring any core object == nil for now but haven't come across a solution or cause

Comment: No error generated either

Comment: Actually think whenever we create a new entity its properties are set to nil before they can be assigned a value in code